# Can I name a variable within an if else statement? Python

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and any language in that case. I started learning about one week ago. I'm trying to create this program which calculates GPA for you just by putting your letter grades in. It is all smooth until the end where I get a error. Ill show you the error

This is the code, error message will be displayed on bottom.

```
$def grades(grades_combined):
  print "This program will tell you what your total GPA for the semester is."
  print "Just enter your grades, and Voila!"

a_1 = 4.4
a = 4.0
a_2 = 3.6
b_1 = 3.4
b = 3.0
b_2 = 2.6
c_1 = 2.4
c = 2
c_2 = 1.6
d_1 = 1.4
d = 1
d_2 = 0.6
f = 0

print """We are going to ask you for all letter grades, in any order. Please
put the letter first, and then the symbol (if any). If there are non-applicable
grades (such as those not entered), just click return."""
print "Press return to continue"
raw_input("Continue!")

grade_1 = raw_input("Grade #1: ")
grade_2 = raw_input("Grade #2: ")
grade_3 = raw_input("Grade #3: ")
grade_4 = raw_input("Grade #4: ")
grade_5 = raw_input("Grade #5: ")
grade_6 = raw_input("Grade #6: ")
grade_7 = raw_input("Grade #7: ")
grade_8 = raw_input("Grade #8: ")


if grade_1 == "a+":
  grade_1_no = a_1
elif grade_1 == "a":
  grade_1_no = a
elif grade_1 == "a-":
  grade_1_no = a_2
elif grade_1 == "b+":
  grade_1_no = b_1
elif grade_1 == "b":
  grade_1_no = b
elif grade_1 == "b-":
  grade_1_no = b2
elif grade_1 == "c+":
  grade_1_no = c_1
elif grade_1 == "c":
  grade_1_no = c
elif grade_1 == "c-":
  grade_1_no = c_2
elif grade_1 == "d+":
  grade_1_no = d_1
elif grade_1 == "d":
  grade_1_no = d
elif grade_1 == "d-":
  grade_1_no = d_2
elif grade_1 == "f":
  grade_1_no = f

  if grade_8 == "a+":
    grade_8_no = a_1
  elif grade_8 == "a":
    grade_8_no = a
  elif grade_8 == "a-":
    grade_8_no = a_2
  elif grade_8 == "b+":
    grade_8_no = b_1
  elif grade_8 == "b":
    grade_8_no = b
  elif grade_8 == "b-":
    grade_8_no = b_2
  elif grade_8 == "c+":
    grade_8_no = c_1
  elif grade_8 == "c":
    grade_8_no = c
  elif grade_8 == "c-":
    grade_8_no = c_2
  elif grade_8 == "d+":
    grade_8_no = d_1
  elif grade_8 == "d":
    grade_8_no = d
  elif grade_8 == "d-":
    grade_8_no = d_2
  elif grade_8 == "f":
    grade_8_no = f

    if grade_2 == "a+":
      grade_2_no = a_1
    elif grade_2 == "a":
      grade_2_no = a
    elif grade_2 == "a-":
      grade_2_no = a_2
    elif grade_2 == "b+":
      grade_2_no = b_1
    elif grade_2 == "b":
      grade_2_no = b
    elif grade_2 == "b-":
      grade_2_no = b_2
    elif grade_2 == "c+":
      grade_2_no = c_1
    elif grade_2 == "c":
      grade_2_no = c
    elif grade_2 == "c-":
      grade_2_no = c_2
    elif grade_2 == "d+":
      grade_2_no = d_1
    elif grade_2 == "d":
      grade_2_no = d
    elif grade_2 == "d-":
      grade_2_no = d_2
    elif grade_2 == "f":
      grade_2_no = f

      if grade_3 == "a+":
        grade_3_no = a1
      elif grade_3 == "a":
        grade_3_no = a
      elif grade_3 == "a-":
        grade_3_no = a_2
      elif grade_3 == "b+":
        grade_3_no = b_1
      elif grade_3 == "b":
        grade_3_no = b
      elif grade_3 == "b-":
        grade_3_no = b_2
      elif grade_3 == "c+":
        grade_3_no = c_1
      elif grade_3 == "c":
        grade_3_no = c
      elif grade_3 == "c-":
        grade_3_no = c_2
      elif grade_3 == "d+":
        grade_3_no = d_1
      elif grade_3 == "d":
        grade_3_no = d
      elif grade_3 == "d-":
        grade_3_no = d_2
      elif grade_3 == "f":
        grade_3_no = f

        if grade_4 == "a+":
          grade_4_no = a_1
        elif grade_4 == "a":
          grade_4_no = a
        elif grade_4 == "a-":
          grade_4_no = a_2
        elif grade_4 == "b+":
          grade_4_no = b_1
        elif grade_4 == "b":
          grade_4_no = b
        elif grade_4 == "b-":
          grade_4_no = b_2
        elif grade_4 == "c+":
          grade_4_no = c_1
        elif grade_4 == "c":
          grade_4_no = c
        elif grade_4 == "c-":
          grade_4_no = c_2
        elif grade_4 == "d+":
          grade_4_no = d_1
        elif grade_4 == "d":
          grade_4_no = d
        elif grade_4 == "d-":
          grade_4_no = d_2
        elif grade_4 == "f":
          grade_4_no = f

          if grade_5 == "a+":
            grade_5_no = a_1
          elif grade_5 == "a":
            grade_5_no = a
          elif grade_5 == "a-":
            grade_5_no = a_2
          elif grade_5 == "b+":
            grade_5_no = b_1
          elif grade_5 == "b":
            grade_5_no = b
          elif grade_5 == "b-":
            grade_5_no = b_2
          elif grade_5 == "c+":
            grade_5_no = c_1
          elif grade_5 == "c":
            grade_5_no = c
          elif grade_5 == "c-":
            grade_5_no = c2
          elif grade_5 == "d+":
            grade_5_no = d1
          elif grade_5 == "d":
            grade_5_no = d
          elif grade_5 == "d-":
            grade_5_no = d2
          elif grade_5 == "f":
            grade_5_no = f

            if grade_6 == "a+":
              grade_6_no = a_1
            elif grade_6 == "a":
              grade_6_no = a
            elif grade_6 == "a-":
              grade_6_no = a_2
            elif grade_6 == "b+":
              grade_6_no = b_1
            elif grade_6 == "b":
              grade_6_no = b
            elif grade_6 == "b-":
              grade_6_no = b_2
            elif grade_6 == "c+":
              grade_6_no = c_1
            elif grade_6 == "c":
              grade_6_no = c
            elif grade_6 == "c-":
              grade_6_no = c_2
            elif grade_6 == "d+":
              grade_6_no = d_1
            elif grade_6 == "d":
              grade_6_no = d
            elif grade_6 == "d-":
              grade_6_no = d_2
            elif grade_6 == "f":
              grade_6_no = f

              if grade_7 == "a+":
                grade_7_no = a_1
              elif grade_7 == "a":
                grade_7_no = a
              elif grade_7 == "a-":
                grade_7_no = a_2
              elif grade_7 == "b+":
                grade_7_no = b_1
              elif grade_7 == "b":
                grade_7_no = b
              elif grade_7 == "b-":
                grade_7_no = b_2
              elif grade_7 == "c+":
                grade_7_no = c_1
              elif grade_7 == "c":
                grade_7_no = c
              elif grade_7 == "c-":
                grade_7_no = c_2
              elif grade_7 == "d+":
                grade_7_no = d_1
              elif grade_7 == "d":
                grade_7_no = d
              elif grade_7 == "d-":
                grade_7_no = d_2
              elif grade_7 == "f":
                grade_7_no = f


grades_combined = ((grade_1_no + grade_2_no + grade_3_no + grade_4_no + grade_5_no,
+ grade_6_no + grade_7_no + grade_8_no)/8)
print "Your total GPA is %r" % grades_combined $
```

This is the error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "STUDY19", line 252, in <module>
    grades_combined = ((grade_1_no + grade_2_no + grade_3_no + grade_4_no + grade_5_no,
NameError: name 'grade_2_no' is not defined`$

PLEASE HELP THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: The variables are only in scope in the if statements. There really should be a better way to do this instead of a ton of ifs and else ifs...

Comment: Read about the M of [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have a look at using a dict to map a string (e.g. "a+") to a value (e.g. 4.4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out this.  Read the code, try to understand what I'm doing.  Read about lists and dicts in Python.  And about comprehensions.  And about loops.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def grade_set(c):
    i = ord('d') - ord(c) + 1.0
    return [ (c + '+', i+0.4), (c, i), (c + '-', i-0.4) ]

GRADES_NUMBERS = dict(sum([ grade_set(c) for c in 'abcd' ], []))
GRADES_NUMBERS['f'] = 0.0

grades = [ None ] * 8
for i in range(len(grades)):
  while True:  # until grade is valid
    grades[i] = raw_input("Grade #%d: " % (i+1))
    if grades[i] in GRADES_NUMBERS:
      break
    print "This is no valid grade, please repeat."

grades_numbers = [ GRADES_NUMBERS[grade] for grade in grades ]

grades_combined = sum(grades_numbers) / len(grades_numbers)

print "Your total GPA is", grades_combined
```

The main idea of computers is to let the computer do the repetitive tasks, not the programmer.  So as soon as you repeat yourself while programming, you do something wrong.  This is so deeply settled in the programming community that they even have an acronym for it: DRY -- Don't Repeat Yourself.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, all you have to do is create the variable names before you start the program.
So before you define the program, just initialise the variables.

```
grade_no_1 = ''
grade_no_2 = ''
>>>
grade_no_8 = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working is because your variable does not exist outside of the `else` scope. Take a look at this example

```
x = 1
z = 0
if x < 0:
  y = 2
else:
  z = x + y  # this will fail because y does not exist in a place that can be accessed
```

If you did this, it will work:

```
x = 1
y = 0
z = 0
if x < 0:
  y = 2
else:
  z = x + y
```

Also, I recommend you take a look at `dictionaries` or `maps` to greatly improve the readibility of your code.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you so much, that got rid of my problem but created another one. I have no idea what this error means, I think its to do with the positive symbols in the string.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "STUDY19.py", line 261, in <module> + grade_6_no + grade_7_no + grade_8_no)/8) 
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```